# Save in a for loop all variables even with NA

Tags: r

I try to run in a loop some api call

I have a dataframe which saves in every iteration all data

However there are some iterations which don't have a specific column

Is there any easy way to save it with an NA without needing to know in every iteration which variable doesn't exist

This is what I use to save the data:

```
dfall <- rbind(dfall, dfiteration)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dplyr::bind_rows` which will automatically add `NA` for columns which are not present.

```
dfall <- dplyr::bind_rows(dfall, dfiteration)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dfall <- rbindlist(list(dfall, dfiteration), fill = TRUE)
```